# Inserting .bbl contents in Latex file breaks reference order

Tags: bibtex, bbl

I'm trying to insert my bibliography in `.bbl` format in my Latex file since the journal I'm submitting to doesn't process `.bib` files well. However I'm running in the following problem. After following this procedure:

- compiling the file (`main.tex`) once with `pdflatex`
- running `bibtex main` to compile the `.bbl` file
- compiling twice more with `pdflatex main.tex`
- deleting the `\bibliography{main.bib}` line and replacing it with the copy pasted contents of `main.bbl`

what I find is the newly compiled PDF has the references appear in the right order in the bibliography, but the numbering in the text is all wrong (for example, reference 1 becomes 24). Can anyone explain me what I'm likely to have done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The numbers in the text should be the same whether you use `\bibliography{main}` or the contents of that file directly. Can you give an example of the incorrect behaviour? Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.  I'm not sure if I quite understand the issue here.

Comment: Basically, the numbers in the text change when I replace `\bibliography` with the contents of the `.bbl` file. Everything else remains the same (which also means the numbers refer effectively to the wrong entries).

Comment: If I understand how `\bibliography` should work correctly, that absolutely should not happen. So I guess I really need to see an example document that reproduces the behaviour to start investigating what is going wrong.

Comment: I have an example, how can I upload a .zip file?

Comment: Ideally you would minimise your example so much that you can just post the few lines of source code directly here into the question. I realise that that takes some time and work on your part, but I for one will not download and open `.zip` files from random strangers on the net (no offence).

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know if it's possible though. I suspect the `.aux` file might play a part. I've just realised that what happens is that the references start counting back from the beginning. So basically there's 23 references, and when I move the `.bbl` in the new references start counting from 24 and run up to 46. It's as if it didn't discard all the old ones, but counted the new ones as if they all came afterwards. I'm using the `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` line by the way, but removing it makes no difference.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to reproduce the issue since you were able to reproduce it in the first place. It's absolutely fine if the example needs additional instructions like (compile with LaTeX, then paste the `.bbl`, then compile again). It's just important that we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The problem was that I did not delete the `.bbl` file, so the references were counted twice and that made the numbers twice what they were supposed to be.

Comment: Mhhhh, that should not be an issue if LaTeX does not load the `.bbl`. Since the `.bbl` is normally loaded by `\bibliography`, removing that line (as you did) should make sure the issue does not appear.

Comment: No idea what happened. It worked. Possibly a bug in the implementation I'm using? Maybe some trace is left in the `.aux` file?

Comment: Something to that effect seems plausible, but without seeing what code you are using that is all speculation.